# Microsoft Graph API : Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: jquery, office365, office365api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to integrate Microsoft Graph authentication and access sharepoint and User's Graph Profile & Pic. I had followed their document https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/authorization/app_authorization
I am able to achieve first step **Authenticate a user and get app authorized** , but not **Acquire an access token**.
I have checked it in Postman, able to get response of access token. Same way I'm trying to do it using **Jquery Ajax** but getting

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

```
$.ajax({ type:"POST",headers: {
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
},
crossOrigin: true,url: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token",data:$.param({grant_type: "authorization_code",redirect_uri:"http://localhost:92",client_id:"8c907c91-1b21-4468-825e-116a4f663249",client_secret:"xxxxxxxxx+=",code:"AQABAAIAAABnfiG-mA6NTae7CdWW7QfdkHvUMGWjMMTjOGwaac7c-pFOjLqj98r37uhB1a1XqjnCL-nK5HcvRIYLhLSUQJZeY9ybZLgWfSl4U0CNdZkwIvee_r6-hPC0Wts0ULDWzkg_nHWLHrquAjJ67T84vuIUv8525xTVdm1Ej07EPRttlske50jy1lruaLX0Wzdj72VnAQ0iRHB_VKwEA-1YB7VOt6qh9756XYkDUfzJMZTxTawT5PVQFyv2joy0TbUYljkyT8RgzdhgT6YV6Rum3cQZg3Amso-0-6umF_1ECfdjmXXxdkscAmsGJHZPrZ1HE8W9zhfsGKlc57QI8J3Qkz-Wfkw8lxcfpp84wHmKnA28jWrww7szXVjjsYmtNsRpSYIvq393QoUZnWN-t0D71510pVAYswr6R3_rR80SMrMvolIpoXeIvPDoOkLszgYEeNRkGAcjVYD5XS4aajyrWqCSUz3xzNt8Vb6x9QBCWxw9xAottQM5ZZIbWc9zrKmmPL8sqkEpJ7Z95QdJjgkFy0qT5c_GQwKNoAiF96iVhyLiULvjwlFYsV9d84QGnz_a5NIt6mMbhgJoY32snEJN7kMyK9uzTHdglkkl-9UgJNnpArN5D8hywaERMN4Fy7RZxnqx9Mt4UnnfK9-RnjvaIE6TIAA",resource:"https://graph.microsoft.com/"}), success: function(result){
    $("#div1").html(result);
},
error: function(){

    $("#div1").html("Error");
}});
```

But in Console, I can see the response form the post method, because for 'Acces-origin' issue, I couldn't get response in my Ajax Success part.
[image: But in Console, I can see the response for POST Method]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Regular web pages can use the XMLHttpRequest object to send and receive data from remote servers, but they're limited by the same origin policy.So the browser is blocking it as it usually allows a request in the same origin for security reasons. Postman wil work because they are not restricted by this policy .

To integrate AAD in javascript, we suggest you to use [azure-activedirectory-library-for-js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) which is a library in javascript for frontend to integrate AAD with a ease ,by using [implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-dev-understanding-oauth2-implicit-grant) ,It also has the advantage of eliminating any requirements for cross origin calls, which are necessary if the JavaScript application is required to contact the token endpoint.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38317973/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-with-microsoft-online-auth) is a thread which discuss same topic and show more about how to use ADAL.JS , please refer to that .

Comment: Is there any official Adal Component available for Angular 2?

Comment: @PraveenR, Currently there is no official Adal Component available for Angular 2 , please refer to [this discussion](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/194), but you could refer to the code sample mentioned (https://github.com/sureshchahal/angular2-adal) in that discussion .

Comment: using that single token, can I get Sharepoint and Office Graph details? Doubt,Generally to access particular resource we should use different token for each resource (as per document). like resource: https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/

Comment: Yes , you could get access token for   [Microsoft Graph APi ](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/)  and use that token to access related resources  with microsoft graph api .

Comment: Microsoft Graph exposes multiple APIs from Office 365 and other Microsoft cloud services through a single endpoint: https://graph.microsoft.com

Comment: Actually, I had tried same. It's authenticated the user,but using that token it was failed to get resource details because the token generated is not matched with AD. generated token is for AD2.0 . I was not sure about, but let me try one more time.

Comment: You need to check whether audience of token is graph api (https://graph.microsoft.com) and you have enough scope in token to access o365 resources .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143251/discussion-between-praveen-r-and-nan-yu-msft).