# Code flow PKCE with OIDC and Azure AD get cors error on /token endpoint

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I saw that the new recommendations (since mid 2019) is to use code flow with PKCE instead of the implicit flow for SPAs. I have an angular spa that uses OIDC client and works fine until it calls the /token endpoint that return a cors error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/oauth2/token' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
```

Is there a way to overcome this error or is there a way to configure Allowed Origins (CORS) in Azure AD or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you integrating B2C using any MSAL package or doing manually? did you follow any doc?

Comment: I am using oidc-client js

Comment: any luck? Stuck with same issue.

Comment: Not yet. I saw that MSAL alfa 2.0 will have support for it but i am not sure how it works since there is no way to configure allow origins in azure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to configure Allowed Origins in Azure AD.

So there are two solutions for you:

1.Use [MSAL.js](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp) with Azure AD B2C.

2.Call the /token endpoint in your server, then you can makes the request to your server.

Reference:

[No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header with Microsoft Online Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38317973/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-with-microsoft-online-auth/38319300#38319300)

Comment: this no longer holds true. According to MS doc you can simply set your app as SPA and the CORS issue will be gone. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#redirect-uri-setup-required-for-single-page-apps