# CORS error Azure functions with B2C - Blazor

Tags: azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c, blazor

I have a Blazor app that is calling an Azure Function that is secured with B2C.  If a call the function directly from a browser, I get redirected to the B2C login and once authenticated the Function returns a Json object as expected.  Now if I make the call within the Blazor app, WITH 'Allow Anonymous Access' on the Function, it works.  Now when I set the Functions access to "Login with Active Directory" I get following:
[image]

I've add my localhost to the Function Cors:

[image]

No sure if I should be added anything when I initialize the connection within Blazor though?
PS. The App authenticates to B2C fine.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: If my answer is helpful, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) error occurs because you are accessing `https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com` endpoint

from `https://localhost` endpoint.

And we can not resolve this error due to the restriction from Azure B2C server side. (Azure AD or Azure AD B2C don't support CORS)

**The workaround** is

You get the token from the server side, call the function in the server, then your app make a call to your server.

Reference:

[No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header with Microsoft Online Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38317973/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-with-microsoft-online-auth/38319300#38319300)